# How to automatically synchronize jquery grid with database table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jqwidget

Any jquery library supports auto synchronize between server side database table and client side jquery grid. Suppose any CRUD operation done by sever side table, it should reflect in client side grid view

Comment: Where is your code and have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

there is not any library which will allow you to sync data between client and server side Changes.

you need to manually trigger reload of jqgrid to load fresh data.